# Final Payment Value Compound Interest Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

A demand loan of $\$4000.00$ is repaid by payments of $\$2000.00$ after two years, $\$2000.00$ after four years, and a final payment after six years.

Interest is $6\%$ compounded quarterly for the first two years, $7\%$ compounded annually for the next two years, and 7% compounded semi-annually thereafter. What is the size of the final payment?

I know how to make all these precursor calculations but I'm very lost on which formula to use to find the final amount.

1. payment. $3000(1+0.0175)^{0.5}$
2. Payment $3000(1+0.04)^{2}$

Comment: Far better to use understanding than to use a formula.

Comment: I get that but I'm struggling with the concept and I think knowing the formula would allow me the context to mentally frame it better.

Comment: I think understanding the mathematics would be a better idea, but each to his/her own.

Comment: If you would like to try and give me a better understanding I would very much like to hear it.

Comment: OK. What's the balance after two years, before the first repayment? What's the balance after two years, after the first reapyment? Same question for after 4 years, before and after the second repayment. Then, what's the balance at the end of six years?

Comment: Oh my goodness... That makes so much sense. I was trying to solve it in one equation but that makes it difficult to include any carryover. Thank you.

Comment: There is the amount of $2000 that should be paid after 4 years. Would the interest be calculated on this amount based on this from the first year or after the first payment is made? This makes a difference and is not very clear from the problem statement. Also see: https://ncalculators.com/interest/compound-interest-calculator.htm

Comment: I think the second payment of 2000 would have to include the value after the first payment is made.

Answer (score 1):

The final payment can be calculated in steps by figuring how much the loan has grown with interest over each time period before each of the stage payments. I'm assuming the interest for each time period is simply the annual rate divided by the number of time periods per year.

$$P_F = ((4000\cdot 1.015^8 -2000)1.07^2 - 2000)1.035^4 = \$997.30$$

Comment: I'm confused where you're getting your N value as I thought it was numbers of years divided by interests compounds per year so for the first 2 years wouldn't it be 4000(1.015)^0.5 as it Would be 2 years divided by 4 (quarterly interest compounds)

Comment: No, it's 1.015 to the power of the number of quarters in 2 years which is 8.Then 1.07 to the power of the number of years which is 2 and finally 1.035 to the power of the number of half years in 2 years which is 4.

Answer (score 0):

$L=4000$, $p_2=2000$, $p_4=2000$, $i^{(4)} =6\%$, $i^{(1)} =7\%$, $i^{(2)} =7\%$. Find $p_6$ solving

$$
L=\frac{p_2}{\left(1+\frac{i^{(4)}}{4}\right)^{2\times 4}} +\frac{p_4}{\left(1+\frac{i^{(4)}}{4}\right)^{2\times 4}\times\left(1+\frac{i^{(1)}}{1}\right)^{2\times 1}}+\frac{p_6}{\left(1+\frac{i^{(4)}}{4}\right)^{2\times 4}\times\left(1+\frac{i^{(1)}}{1}\right)^{2\times 1}\times\left(1+\frac{i^{(2)}}{2}\right)^{2\times 2}}
$$